# How to `build` an old Adonis project?

Tags: adonis.js

I'm heritating from an old Adonis project which the server is not running anymore. I'm trying to find out why.

I'd like to know how to **rebuild** it knowing the `package.json` below:

```
{
  "name": "myproject-backend-server",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch app --watch bootstrap --watch config --watch .env --watch providers server.js",
    "start": "node --harmony_proxies server.js",
    "pretest": "ENV_PATH=.env.test ./ace migration:run",
    "test": "node --harmony_proxies bin/test.js",
    "posttest": "ENV_PATH=.env.test ./ace migration:rollback",
    "lint": "standard app/{**,**/**}/*.js tests/{*,**/*}.js",
    "emails:html": "for i in $(ls ./tmpl-emails); do if [ \"${i:0:1}\" != \"_\" ]; then echo \"build ./resources/views/emails/${i%.*}.njk\" && mjml -m -r ./tmpl-emails/$i -o ./resources/views/emails/${i%.*}.njk; fi; done"
  },
  "standard": {
    "globals": [
      "make",
      "use",
      "describe",
      "before",
      "after",
      "it",
      "afterEach",
      "beforeEach"
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "adonis-ace": "^3.0.4",
    "adonis-auth": "^1.0.4",
    "adonis-commands": "^2.1.2",
    "adonis-fold": "^3.0.3",
    "adonis-framework": "^3.0.4",
    "adonis-lucid": "^3.0.15",
    "adonis-mail-provider": "^2.0.2",
    "adonis-middleware": "^1.0.8",
    "adonis-validation-provider": "^3.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "date.js": "^0.3.1",
    "fecha": "^2.3.0",
    "firebird-promise": "0.0.1",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.15",
    "intel": "^1.1.2",
    "is-uuid": "^1.0.2",
    "json2csv": "^3.7.3",
    "make-random-string": "^1.0.5",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mysql": "^2.12.0",
    "nexmo": "^2.4.1",
    "node-exceptions": "^1.0.3",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "random-int": "^1.0.0",
    "schemata": "^3.2.0",
    "slug": "^0.9.1",
    "standard": "^8.5.0",
    "yargs": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "App": "./app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "co": "^4.6.0",
    "co-fs": "^1.2.0",
    "co-mocha": "^1.1.3",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "globby": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.6",
    "mailparser": "^0.6.1",
    "mjml": "^3.2.2",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "ms": "^0.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8",
    "standard": "^8.5.0",
    "supertest": "^2.0.1",
    "yargs": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

Building with `npm run build` doesn't work (missing script).

Answer (score 0):

Build is not a command in your package.json
Run

```
node ace build
```

or add

```
"build":"node ace build"
```

to your package.json and run npm run build

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm getting this error message: `build is not registered with ace`

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of adonisjs, is your codebase in JS or TS, if it's in JS, i dont think there's anyneed to build

Comment: I guess it's in JS...